# Line spacing not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get each player name with its average score on a separate lines, my code is:

```
print(sorted(player_averages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

I have tried `\n` but doesn't work, are there any other creative ways in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop to print your players:

```
for name, average in sorted(player_averages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(name, average)
```

To do it on one line, you'll need to use a generator expression formatting each name-average pair:

```
print(*('{}: {}'.format(name, average)
        for name, average in sorted(player_averages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]),
      sep='\n')
```